# How to given value for paint.setcolor(Color.Spinnervalue) using spinner directly in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have spinner.That contain list of String . I need to pass that String to paint.setcolor(Color.Spinnervalue) directly.

My code is

```
   String spincolurpos =          spincolour.getItemAtPosition(spincolour.getSelectedItemPosition()).
                    toString();
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(Color.spincolurpos); // Text Color
                        paint.setStrokeWidth(120); // Text Size
                     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawableBitmap); 
                        canvas.drawBitmap(drawableBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                        canvas.drawText(txtdrawtext.toString(), 50, 50, paint);
                        image.setImageBitmap(drawableBitmap);
```

I do not  want to make if condition to check the spinner value and hot code it. I want to pass directly.I think may be it's a silly Question.But i can't able to get answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
String spincolurpos=spincolour.getItemAtPosition(spincolour.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(spincolurpos));
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(120); // Text Size
                 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawableBitmap); 
                    canvas.drawBitmap(drawableBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                    canvas.drawText(txtdrawtext.toString(), 50, 50, paint);
                    image.setImageBitmap(drawableBitmap);
```